# Using string with special characters with quo(), in rlang package

Tags: r, string, evaluation, rlang

I have two variables, a and b. I try to compute a-b using expression with the rlang package. quo(a-b) returns, as expected:

```
<quosure: global>
~a - b
```

However, I have a and b as strings. So I tried: quo(!!sym("a-b")), which results in

```
<quosure: global>
~`a-b` #(note the '')
```

So the question is why I obtain ~'a-b', and not ~a-b. How can I simply obtain ~a-b. Note that quo(!!sym("a")) returns, as expected:

```
<quosure: global>
~a
```

So it seems that there is an issue with the - sign (same will occur with *). Is it related to some special characters / non standard evaluation issues? How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parse_expr`...

```
library(rlang)
q0 <- quo(a - b)
q1 <- quo(!!parse_expr("a - b"))
identical(q0, q1)
# [1] TRUE
```

...or `parse_quo`:

```
q2 <- parse_quo("a - b", global_env())
identical(q0, q2)
# [1] TRUE
```

See the discussion here: https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/116

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what is the difference between the sym() and parse_exp()? It is unclear from the discussion mentioned.

Comment: You should ask it as a new question, so other people who have the same question can find it when they search for it. But in short, `sym("a-b")` creates one symbol `\`a-b\``, in the sense of `\`a-b\` <- 5`.